# Converting time field omitting time and returning null values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, convert, time, date

I have a time field in my shapefile that is formatted as HH:mm:ss.s
It is a text field, and I want to convert it to a date so I can calculate time elapsed across rows (if there's a better way to do this let me know).
Basically, each row is a point on a route, and I want to use the time field to calculate the amount of time elapsed between the first and last points on the route.

I tried using the convert time field tool, setting the input format as HH:mm:ss.s, and the output type as DATE. The output field however only shows values of 01/01/2001 for some rows and  for other rows.
[image]

time is the input field and time_c is the output field

I'm not sure what's going wrong here, here is what shows up in the geoprocessing results window:

[image]

I tried adding the date data to the field as well to make the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.s, but it still didn't work:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried altering the precision in the time field to only allow "ss.s" instead of what it has there: "ss.sss"?

Comment: according to the arcgis resource center site, "Although the format only shows one decimal place, any number of decimal places can be used." I did try that though and it still didn't work.

Comment: Since your input data only contains hour/minute/second information, maybe converting it to a day just can't be done. And since it doesn't have that information it's giving you NULL/Jan 1st/2001 results? According to the "Supported field formats" (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005z00000006000000) you need to have a YYYY for it to work properly and a MM is suggested.

Comment: Shapefiles don't support time fields with greater than day precision.  Even file geodatabase doesn't support subsecond timestamps.

Comment: So I tried adding date data to the field, so now it's in the format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.s, and the output was the same, just the date this time was 11/06/2015 (the correct date) instead of 01/01/2001.

Comment: That seems weird to me. I've run into finicky issues like this with ArcMap, perhaps a good old machine reboot is necessary? Other than that I'm not sure that I can help further.

Comment: ok thanks I exported them to a geodatabase and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shapefiles utilize dBase-III+ date values ('D' type), which are restricted to day resolution.  If you need second resolution, you'll need to use a personal, file, or enterprise geodatabase.

It would probably be best to round the fractional seconds to the nearest second, since Desktop's time structure (struct tm) doesn't support subsecond precision at this time.